# NSUserDefaults, Core Data or neither?

Tags: persistence, swift-language

Everytime I press a certain button, it should remove a random index from  a dictionary and then save that dictionary everytime its modified. I have done this using NSUserDefaults. I have found that all the info persists even after turning the app off and back on. Although, when I delete the app from the simulator or execute "xcrun simctl erase all" on the simulator, the dictionary goes back to what it was initially. That said, I'm wondering if using Core Data will persist data even after deleting an app or resetting an iphone. If not, what are some other options?

Also, assuming Core Data is the solution, I have found it very hard to use it to save a dictionary, let alone save it everytime an index is removed from the dictionary.

Comment: Your core data sqlite database will also get deleted when the app is removed from the phone, so it will have the same behavior as NSUserDefaults. Maybe if you describe the goal you want to achieve? Why do you want the information to persist even after the user has decided (s)he doesn't want your app anymore?

Comment: That's one reason why users actually delete and reinstall an app: To get rid of everything the app stored. You would need a very, very good reason to circumvent that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Data stored in iCloud using CloudKit can persist through app removal and is also accessible from other devices.

Comment: You have to decide what you actually want. Do you WANT data to persist through app removals? Do you WANT data to be shared between devices? Important, do you WANT your app to rely on having an internet connection? That's what you need to think about first.

Answer (score 0):

UICKeyChainStore using to achieve your scenario in my project.I believe,it will help you. once you uninstall the app it will display the value.

Github Link : [click to access the sample usage process](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore)

```
deviceId_key = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"deviceId" service:@"com.app.grid"];
    if (deviceId_key==nil)
    {
        [UICKeyChainStore setString:deviceId forKey:@"deviceId" service:@"com.app.grid"];

        deviceId_key = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"deviceId" service:@"com.app.grid"];

    }
```

Comment: Why do you advice to use some particular third party library, instead of telling him or her to use the keychain, which is built-in and either doesn't require a third party library, or can use any of a number of libraries.

Comment: I really really hope that the keychain is not abused for usual data storage operations.